# How can I load several CSVs with the same columns but in different column orders into a single table using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a set of 200 CSV files in blob storage in a single folder that each contain the exact same set of 90 columns with the exact same set of column headers, but in some of the files, these columns appear in a different order. For example, in some of the files, the first column is named "transaction_data" while in others, "transaction_data" may be the 8th or 73rd column. I receive several of these files every day via an automated process, and I am not able to manually review them or bucket them into logical groups based on their column orders.

There is no way to know from the filename or any file metadata which of the files have the columns in the "right order" (the order in which the columns appear in my SQL Database table I'm using as the sink), it's more-or-less random. I know this problem is solvable by using some preprocessing like a Python script to force the files to all have columns in the correct order, but that feels like a lot of extra work, time, and potential cost when this is something it seems ADF should handle natively and I'm just doing something wrong.

What I have right now is a data flow where:

- Source settings "Allow Schema Drift" is checked
- Source options are using wildcard paths to find all *.csv files
- Sink is an Azure SQL Database table
- Sink options "Allow schema drift" is checked
- Sink mapping "Auto mapping" is checked

But what's happening is that whatever file it picks up first, it's using that file's column order and applying it to all the rest of the files that are processed. As a result, the Sink table will have some rows where, e.g., the data for "transaction_data" is in the wrong column. There must be some way to force it to evaluate each file on its own? As far as I can tell from ADF's documentation and the info popups, it should be using the field names from my CSVs to do the mapping, in fact when I check the "Auto mapping" option on the Mapping tab of my sink, the text reads "All inputs mapped by name including drifted columns". This is exactly what I want, but isn't the behavior I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to make this work with a data flow, so I ended up using a foreach loop in my pipeline instead, which worked just fine. Bummer because it's much more of a pain to set up but at least it works.